# Pagination problem

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

I have two custom rewrite rules:

```
add_rewrite_rule('foo/bar/?', 'index.php?post_type=foo', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('foo/bar/([a-z]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=foo&bar=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Which gives me posts that match a custom variable `bar`. However, I want to handle pagination too, thus when a number succeeds `/bar/` wordpress should treat it as a page number. I wrote:

```
add_rewrite_rule('foo/bar/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=foo&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

In my custom function which is attached to `pre_get_posts`, I process the page number:

```
if($query->get('paged')) {
    $query->set('paged', intval($query->get('paged')));
}
```

However, when user accesses, say, `foo/bar/2`, wordpress automatically appends `/page/2/`, (e.g. in the address bar I get the following URL: `foo/bar/2/page/2/`).

Although the pagination itself works fine (I get the desired records as expected for each page) this `/page/n/` messes up my links on the page and it is an unnecessary duplication in my url. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I don't think you need that rule on `pre_get_posts` - it says "if value is set, set it", and it is set earlier by `WP_Query->parse_query()`

Answer (score 0):

The function `redirect_canonical()` is 'responsible' for your problem.

Your default WordPress pagination (with core functions) is not gonna work if you do this, but you can filter out the pagination for your particular custom url:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'wp230913_canonical', 10, 2 );

function wp230913_canonical( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if ( preg_match( "#foo/bar/[0-9]+/page/[0-9]+#", $redirect_url ) ) {
        return $requested_url;
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

My recomandation is to change the pagination base for the whole site, changing `$wp_rewrite->pagination_base`